# Saving processed excel data into already made template having data inside it using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

excel_file = 'access_control_data.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file)

df.sort_values(by=['Name', 'Time'], inplace=True)

df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])


result_df = df.groupby('Name')['Time'].agg(['first', 'last']).reset_index()

result_df['Reporting Time'] = result_df['first'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
result_df['Closing Time'] = result_df['last'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

mask = result_df['Reporting Time'] == result_df['Closing Time']
result_df.loc[mask, 'Closing Time'] = '16:30:00'


result_df.drop(['first', 'last'], axis=1, inplace=True)

result_df.rename(columns={'Name': 'STAFF'}, inplace=True)
```

The code snippet above reads data from an Excel file, sorts it based on name and time, extracts reporting and closing times for each individual, ensures consistency in closing time, and finally, renames the 'Name' column to 'STAFF'. The result is a processed DataFrame ready for further analysis or reporting.

I want to Save the result into an already exiting excel template having multiple sheets.

The sheets has data inside it already. how do I replace the existing data with the new result

I tried naming a variable called existing template and assign it to the data I want to write into with the name of the sheet but it didn't work out.